# struts2 UpDownselect not giving full ordered list on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, struts2

I am using Struts2 UpDownSelect component.
But when i am submitting the form instead of getting the comma seperated sorted list I am geeting just one element which was last selected in the list.

JSp :

```
<div class="search-area">
    <s:form id="saveTableOrder" method="post" action="save-operator-table-order" name="tableOrderForm" >
        <div class="inputField">
            <s:select id="operatorSelect" name="selectedOperator" value="selectedOperator" key="operator" list="operators" listKey="operatorName" listValue="operatorName" labelposition="left" onChange="this.form.submit()"/>
        </div>

        <div class="inputField">

            <s:updownselect name="tableOrder" list="tablesOrder"  key="manageOrder" moveDownLabel="Down" moveUpLabel="Up" value="tableOrder" labelposition="left" ></s:updownselect>
        </div>

         <div class="submitButtons">
            <s:submit key="general.button.save" />
            <input id="operator-table-order-cancel" type="submit" name="action:cancel-operator-table-order" value="<s:property value="getText('general.button.cancel')"/>" />
        </div>

    </s:form>
</div>
```

Action Class :

```
public class ManageTableOrderAction extends BOActionSupport {



    private String tableOrder;

    private List<OperatorDTO> operators;

    private String selectedOperator;

    List<String> order = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    @SkipValidation
    public String execute() {
        init();
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    private void init() {
        //something
          order.add("one");
            order.add("one");
           .......
    }


    public String saveTableOrder() {
        if (tableOrder != null && !tableOrder.isEmpty()) {
            tableOrder = lobbyTableService.saveTableOrder(selectedOperator, tableOrder);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public String cancelTableOrder() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public List<OperatorDTO> getOperators() {
        init();
        return operators;
    }


    public void setOperators(List<OperatorDTO> operators) {
        this.operators = operators;
    }


    public String getSelectedOperator() {
        return selectedOperator;
    }


    public void setSelectedOperator(String selectedOperator) {
        this.selectedOperator = selectedOperator;
    }


    public String getTableOrder() {
        return tableOrder;
    }


    public void setTableOrder(String tableOrder) {
        this.tableOrder = tableOrder;
    }


    public List<String> getTablesOrder() {
       return order;
    }


    public void setTablesOrder(List<String> tablesOrder) {
        this.order = tablesOrder;
    }
```

Now when clicking submit button. My form is submitted but in tableOrder I get only one element of the list.
I was expecting full list in comma seperated form.
I searched a lot no where found anybody having the same issue 
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Which version of Struts2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<s:head/>` tag to your JSP, which adds Struts2 `utils.js`. This file holds javascript functions which are required for `<s:updownselect>` tag to work properly.

Comment: You solution worked. However after adding <s:head> .Each time after logging in I am seeing the struts utils.js in my browser . Than again I have to change URL and then it works fine. So after every log in i am getting this page once                     .URL :http://localhost:8080/backoffice/struts/utils.js    Do you have any idea what wrong I am doing

Comment: @nimit: Hard to tell w/o seeing configuration. Ask another question and show login configuration/code.